# checked or not checked buttons, javaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, radio-button, checked

why isnt this working? It only works on my last radiobutton. If I click the last one, my
**div id="textInfo"** shows, and if I then press the first o second it goes away. But I also
want the **div** to show when I press the first or second radio button.

At the end I want to show diffrent info in my div, depends on witch radio button you click.

```
    const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.radio');
    const info = document.getElementById("txtInfo");
    console.log(btn);

    btn.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', show)
    });



    function show(e) {
        btn.forEach((e) => {
            if (e.checked) {
                info.style.transform = "scale(1)";
                //console.log(e.id + "True")
            } else {
                info.style.transform = "scale(0)";
                //console.log(e.id + "False")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: `btn.forEach(btn => { btn.addEventListener('click', show) });` works but for your own sanity (and for every other reader of your code) please rename the "outer" `btn` to `buttons` because its a collection "buttons".

Comment: what is `txtInfo`s  tag? span or what

Comment: Actually, this code will always set scale to 1 because `txtInfo` wont be scaled until one of radios get clicked and since you  have atleast one  checked radio anyways (cant uncheck all) so, scale(0) is unreachable.

Comment: Oh, yes now I get why it doesnt work as I want. Thanks. 

Hmm, so how do I get it work the way I want? :)